# Tu "Introduction to manifolds" Proposition 16.8

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Consider the following fragment from Tu's book *An introduction to manifolds* (pp.181-182 of the second edition, section 16 "Lie algebra's").

[image]

Why exactly is the function

$$F: G \times I \to \mathbb{R}: (g,t) \mapsto \frac{d}{ds}\Big\vert_{s=t} f(g c(t))$$

smooth (= $C^\infty$?) I understand that $(g,s) \mapsto f(gc(s))$ is $C^\infty$, but I don't know why this implies that $F$ is smooth as well, although it is something that can be expected.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It is definitely not so easy (we want differentiability in both variables, for instance).

Comment: $f\circ \mu\circ \text{id}\times c:G\times I\to G$ is a smooth function. All of the involved maps are smooth.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes typo. It is smooth simply  because $g\cdot c$ is smooth, so is $f$ and so $f\circ (g\cdot c)$ is as well.  Are you asking how to prove this fact?

Comment: @Matematleta No, that is clear.

Comment: Well, since it is a composition of group multiplication, $f$ , and $c$
 , it is smooth. Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially because of three facts:

1. The $k$th derivative of a $C^r$ function ($r\geq k$) is $C^{r-k}$, and in particular any derivative of a $C^\infty$ function is $C^\infty$.
2. Any mixed partial derivative of order $k$ of a $C^r$ function ($r\geq k$) is invariant under permutations of the order of the derivatives; in particular one can take any mixed partial derivative of a $C^\infty$ function in any order one likes.
3. For $M$, $N$, and $P$ $C^\infty$ manifolds, a function $F:M\times N\to P$ is $C^r$ iff all mixed partials $D_{\text{along }M}^i D_{\text{along }N}^j F$, $i+j\leq r$ exist and are continuous iff all mixed partials $\partial_{x_1}^{i_1}\cdots\partial_{x_m}^{i_m}\partial_{y_1}^{j_1}\cdots\partial_{y_n}^{j_n} F$, $i_1+\cdots + i_m+ j_1 +\cdots +j_n\leq r$ exist and are continuous, where $(x_1,...,x_m)$ and $(y_1,...,y_n)$ are anonymous local charts for $M$ and $N$, respectively. (And $F$ is $C^\infty$ iff it's $C^r$ for any $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$.)

---

Thus since $(g,t)\mapsto f(gc(t))$ is $C^\infty$ one has

$$D^i_{\text{along }G}D^j_{\text{along }I}F(g,t)
=D^i_{\text{along }G}D^j_{\text{along }I}\dfrac{d}{dt}f(gc(t))
=D^i_{\text{along }G}D^{j+1}_{\text{along }I}f(gc(t)),$$

whence $F$ is $C^\infty$.

(Or: $D^i_{\text{along }G}D^j_{\text{along }I}F(g,t)
=\dfrac{d}{dt} D^i_{\text{along }G}D^j_{\text{along }I}f(gc(t))$)

It might be instructive to consider the case of $G=\mathbb{R}$.